# How to use ARM Complete deployment 'by resource'?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I´m migrating my infrastructure in azure to ARM Templates, I´m doing progressively, so I need to use the `Incremental` option because I do not have all the resources in templates yet. 
But I would like to know if there´s an option to reflect my Template to a specific resource.

For example:

I have a service bus with two topics in my resource group and two subscriptions for each topic:

```
-topic01
   -Sub01
   -Sub02

-topic02
   -Sub03
   -Sub04
```

But in my ARM Template I removed the `Sub04` subscription. When I deploy it in Incremental Mode, I realized that the `Sub04` still there. I think thats the expected behaviour, but I would like to reflect my ARM Template to this ServiceBus resource without deleting it, because it will change the connection keys and I dont have my AppServices(that use this keys) automated yet.

Is there a buit-in solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to delete a resource without deleting it? Anyway, in incremental mode no deletes will happen. In complete mode they will.

If you remove Sub04 from the template, only Sub04 will get removed (not the Service Bus instance, well if the Service Bus is in the template).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is what Terraform does with an execution plan.  To the best of my knowledge there is an in [Preview Powershell command which would allow this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if)

It should return back what the result of your ARM template would be if deployed.